# Using template defined in light dom inside a Polymer element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to get a template moved from the DOM to inside the element.

Here is my elements:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../polymer-ui-icon/polymer-ui-icon.html">

<polymer-element name="bt-sortable-list" attributes="drag name list">
  <template>
    BOOM
    <template binding ref="itemTemplate" repeat="{{list}}" id="repeatTemplate">
    </template>
    <template id="itemTemplate">
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('bt-sortable-list', {
      ready: function() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        contentStr = this.trim(innerHTML);
        var parsed = markdown.toHTML(content);
        this.$.itemTemplate.innerHTML = parsed;
        this.list = [{name: 'Item 1', id: 'item1'}, {name: 'Item 2', id: 'item2'}, {name: 'Item 3', id: 'item3'}];
        this.$.repeatTemplate.model = this.list;
      }
    });

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And here is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/bt-sortable-list/bt-sortable-list.html">
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Sortable List</h3>
  <bt-sortable-list>
  <template 
      Name {{name}}
  </template>
  </bt-sortable-list>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to get the template in test.html to be used inside of the bt-sortable-list custom element.  The general idea is that the custom element will handle the list and other things, while letting the html that is using the element to define how a list element will be displayed.  I've tried programmatically adding the template as shown.  I've also tried not having the template under the bt-sortable-list element.  I've also tried using a content element to get the templates contents in test.html.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the (light dom) content of a custom element you need to include an insertion point in your element (`<content>`):

http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html#shadow-dom-subtrees

However, insertion points are purely placeholders for rendering nodes in the shadow DOM. What you're after is a bit different because it's using Polymer's data binding features to bridge the light dom world outside of your Polymer element, with the shadow dom world inside of it.

I was able to get things working by dynamically creating the `<template>` in `ready()` and using `ref` to reference it:

```
var t = document.createElement('template');
t.id = 'itemTemplate';
t.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;

this.list = [{name: 'Item 1', id: 'item1'},
             {name: 'Item 2', id: 'item2'},
             {name: 'Item 3', id: 'item3'}];

this.shadowRoot.appendChild(t);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/IVodePuS/3/edit

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing.  After I reread the doc on shadow DOM subtrees, it definitely made more sense.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @ebidel Is something like this still possible in Polymer 1.2+? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645114/polymer-dom-repeat-binding-to-content