# Data-binding between nested polymer elements

Tags: data-binding, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Suppose I have two distinct `polymer-elements`

One should be embedded inside the other using the `content` placeholder. 
Is it possible to do data-binding between these two nested `polymer-elements` ?

I tried, but I can't get it to work: http://jsbin.com/IVodePuS/11/

According to http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#binding data-binding between `polymer-elements` should work (in those examples they were done inside the `template` tag without using a `content` placeholder).

## Update:

Scott Miles clarified that data-binding only works on the `template` level.
However in my case I don't know the exact `template` beforehand but I want to allow the user of my `parent-element` to specify which `child-element` it should contain (provided that there are different `child-elements`.
I think this question is related to this one: [Using template defined in light dom inside a Polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522118/using-template-defined-in-light-dom-inside-a-polymer-element/21532931#21532931)

I updated the example below to highlight his:

```html
<polymer-element name="parent-element" >
  <template >
    <div>Parent data: {{data1}} </div>
    <content />
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('parent-element', {
      data1 : '',
      ready: function() {
        this.data='parent content';
      }
    });

  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="child-element" attributes="data2">
   <template>
    <div>Parent data: {{data2}} </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('child-element', {
      data2 : '',
      ready: function() {
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="child2-element" attributes="data2">
   <template>
    <div>Parent data: {{data2}} </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('child2-element', {
      data2 : '',
      ready: function() {
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The user can choose which `child-element` to embed:

```html
<parent-element data1 = "test">
  <child-element data2="{{data1}}"/>
</parent-element>

<parent-element data1 ="test" >
  <child2-element data2="{{data1}}"/>
</parent-element>
```

## Workaround:

The only workaround I found was to add `change watcher` and use `getDistributedNodes()` to get the child element and manually set `data2` to `data`:

```html
<polymer-element name="parent-element" >
  <template >
    <div>Parent data: {{data}} </div>
    <content id="content"/>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('parent-element', {
      data : '',
      ready: function() {
        this.data='parent content';
      },
      dataChanged : function() {
          contents = this.$.content.getDistributedNodes();
          if (contents.length > 0) {
              contents[0].data2 = this.data;
          }
      },
    });

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need to do. I will try your solution today

Answer (score 6):

Polymer data-binding works by attaching a model to a whole subtree.

You wrote:

```
<parent-element>
  <child-element data2="{{data}}"/>
</parent-element>
```

this implies a rule that the parentNode provides the binding model. But now imagine you wanted to write:

```
<parent-element>
  <div>
    <child-element data2="{{data}}"></child-element>
  </div>
</parent-element>
```

Now you have a problem.

Instead, in Polymer examples, you will notice that the `{{}}` are (almost always) inside of a template. For example, if I define:

```
<polymer-element name="host-element" attributes="data" noscript>
<template>
  <parent-element data1="{{data}}">
    <child-element data2="{{data}}"></child-element>
  </parent-element>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Now, I have a model context (`host-element`) that I can use to bind things together in the entire subtree described by the template.

Note that I don't need `attributes="data"` for this to work. I added that so host-element exposes `data` and I can do this:

```
<host-element data="test"></host-element>
```

http://jsbin.com/IVodePuS/15/edit

Comment: Minor note that this jsbin only seems to work on Canary. With the polyfills, it appears that the use of the host-element needs to follow its declaration.

Comment: Element usage never needs to follow declaration. Where are you testing? I tested it in Chrome 34, FF 29, IE 11 and it worked fine as is.

Comment: My mistake. Something was funky with my machine. Post crash & reboot, the jsbin works perfectly on Chrome 35, where I ran it before.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottMiles for the feedback. However my specific use case is that I don't know the exact template during design time but only during runtine. Imagine I have two different `child-elements` and I want the user of my `parent-element` to choose `child-element` should be used. I updated the question.

Comment: sheesh polymer is just so complex, yuk

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm. Parent element is publishing property data, that can by 2 way data bound. This way the child element gets the same data.

```
<polymer-element name="custom-element">
<template>
    <parent data="{{data}}">
        <child data="{{data}}"></child>
    </parent>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        ready: function() {

        },
        data: {}
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in Polymer >= 1.0 this should be done using "[Auto-binding template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind)".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could benefit from a specific example and more information about the link. Helpful hints do make great comments though.  See [answer] for some helpful suggestions.