# Polymer: passing attributes from container component to an item component

Tags: dom, polymer, web-component

I have 2 components:
x-container and x-item.
they have a hierarchy similar to < table > and < tr > or to < tr > and < td >...
Hence x-item components are only effective when they're inside an x-container component:

```
<x-container>
    <x-item></x-item>
</x-container>
```

I want to pass an attribute value from x-container to x-item:

```
<x-container att="value">
    <x-item></x-item>
</x-container>
```

In this case I need value to be visible to x-item - is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works out of the box if you know the structure of `x-container` beforehand ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wexov/1/edit?html,output)):

```
<polymer-element name="x-container" attributes="value">
  <template>
    <x-item value="{{value}}"></x-item>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-container', {
      value : null,
      ready: function() {
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="x-item" attributes="value">
  <template>
    <div>x-item value:{{value}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-item', {


    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<x-container value="test"></x-container>
```

If you want to dynamically create the relationship of `x-container` and `x-item` refer to these SO threads:

[Data-binding between nested polymer elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522037/data-binding-between-nested-polymer-elements)

[Using template defined in light dom inside a Polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522118/using-template-defined-in-light-dom-inside-a-polymer-element/21532931#21532931)

[What is the best way to implement declarative collection rendering with Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839612/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-declarative-collection-rendering-with-polymer)